# How to route Codeigniter URL with multiple parameters?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Codeigniter URL route.php has following routing format.

```
localhost/male/all-grades
localhost/male/grade-9
localhost/male/grade-10
localhost/male/grade-11
localhost/female/all-grades
localhost/female/grade-9
localhost/female/grade-10
localhost/female/grade-11
```

Second parameter has 1 or 2 for male and females. And 2nd parameter has few grades such as grade 9, 10, 11 and all grades(12 parameter for all).

```
`$route['(?i)^(males|females)/(all-grades|grade-9|grade-10|grade-11']   = 'main/userinfo/$1/$2';
```

I think i have done a mistake here and can't find it using `$1` and `$2`.